# How to uninstall from `Carton`

Tags: perl, cpanm

I have `Carton` environment and install modules into `./local/` from `cpanfile`. But now I do not require some modules and want to remove some.

I can remove `./local` folder and install modules from scratch but this take a time. I have found [this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ckyH5a9kDMAJ:https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIYAGAWA/carton-v0.9.10/docs/carton-uninstall.pod+&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ua)

```
carton uninstall Module
```

But it does not exists anymore.

Is there something like `carton uninstall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I workaround I just delete `local` folder and install modules from scratch:

```
rm -r local
carton
```

**UPD**

> Note: This can take a while to install from scratch.

Thus to save time you can pass [`--notest`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#-n,-notest) option to `cpanm` via [PERL_CPANM_OPT](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#PERL_CPANM_OPT):

```
PERL_CPANM_OPT=--notest carton
```

Or if you you want to prevent querying for new versions:

```
carton install --deployment
```

This will install modules without testing them. This is safe in compare to previous command because you know that module was installed before (tests were PASS)

Comment: that solution is not ideal. If you have lots of installed modules, it will take forever to reinstall them

Comment: @Petru: This is the only way for now. Alternative was not proposed for two years. So it is not worth downvoting

Comment: @Petru: Now days you can use `cpm` it installs very fast. A couple of minutes for about 400 modules ;-)